# is there a way to add patch version in CN1 version number

Tags: codenameone

To my knowledge CN1 does not allow to keep patch version in the Version number. Please advise if there is a way I can do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Codename One only supports decimals because Android and iOS handle versioning very differently. It's really hard to create common code that works everywhere that's still easy to use.

As a workaround you can use the build hint `ios.bundleVersion=1.1.1`. Notice that this overrides the version value you set in the UI.

Comment: @Shai..Thank You Is there a way to do it for android as well .Please advise. Now I have used version 1.2 in codenameone version file and made a release build, so when I upload the build to google play with same Release name(1.1.0) it will show like 1.1.0 (2)  as there is another one exists already. But internally it has cn1 version 1.2, So if I release this to store will this go as Version 1.2 on the App page or 1.1.0 as given by me. Please advise how can i make sure it will go as 1.1 in google play.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is I would like override the version in Google play without upgrading the version name(which users notice). I'm ok to change the Version Number(internal build numbers). Please advise.

Comment: Google won't let you submit a new version without user version changes

Comment: @Shai..I change version but I want to keep the Version Name same. Please see the documentation from Android. versionName — A string used as the version number shown to users. This setting can be specified as a raw string or as a reference to a string resource.
The value is a string so that you can describe the app version as a <major>.<minor>.<point> string, or as any other type of absolute or relative version identifier. The versionName has no purpose other than to be displayed to users.

Comment: @Shai..I found this as example build.gradle file. I would like to which refers "versionName" in CN1. Is there a we can override it. Please advise.- android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.company.app_name"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1   //Change this to upgrade your app on PlayStore (Not shown there)
    versionName "1.1.0" //This was just to display on PlayStore
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

Comment: Version name is coded to the version you submit in the settings, we don't provide a way to override it.